# jquery autocomplete makes mCustomScrollbar scroll to top on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have implemented the mCustomScrollbar plugin in my backoffice interfaces. It works fine. But in one of my forms, I have a city field that needs the autocomplete.

The autocomplete also works fine. But when I select one of the item from autocomplete source data, the mCustomScrollbar plugin automatically brings me to the top of the scrolling content and I have to click a second time for the item to actually be selected.

This is how I implemented the scrollbar plugin :

```
$('#mainContent').mCustomScrollbar({
        set_height: height,
        scrollInertia: 500,
        scrollEasing: "easeInOutQuad",
        mouseWheel: 20,
        autoDraggerLength: true,
        advanced: {
            updateOnBrowserResize: true,
            updateOnContentResize: false
        }
    });
```

And this is how I implemented the autocomplete :

```
el.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: activityAutocomplete,
            dataType: "json",
            data: request,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    data.push({
                        label: "Pas de résultat"
                    });
                }
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    //If overflow edge of window, the autocomplete flips to top of input
    position: { collision: "flip" },
    autofocus: true,
    delay: 150,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        //ui.hide();
        //The following code resizes the input by bluring it.
        setTimeout(function () { el.autoGrowInput(); }, 50);


    },
    appendTo: '#autocomplete-tb-city-' + el.parents('.item').attr('id')
});
```

I hope you'll find something wrong here, i've been working on this for like 3 days !

EDIT: This is the generated autocomplete markup.

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"   role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Angers</a</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Amiens</a</li>
</ul>
```

I must add something might be importante : it brings me to top even on RIGHT CLICK !!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue with autocomplete. Selecting any autocomplete items scrolls the window to the top.

I saw your comment [here](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/comment-page-7#comment-13877), and I think you got the solution.

Using hint you mentioned in the above link, I went through mcustomscrollbar.js code and just commented out lines 533 and 534 and yeppy it worked for me.

Thanks for the hint. Cheers !!

Answer (score 9):

A new version of custom `scrollbars` have an advanced option `autoScrollOnFocus`.

Example:

```
        $($element).find('> .scrollbars').mCustomScrollbar({
            horizontalScroll: false,
            autoDraggerLength: true,
            autoHideScrollbar: true,
            advanced:{
                autoScrollOnFocus: false,
                updateOnContentResize: true,
                updateOnBrowserResize: true
            }
        });
```

Comment: setting `autoScrollOnFocus: false` solved my issues with this plugins field focus error.

Answer (score 0):

might be an anchor-related problem? what is the href on the generated items for auto-complete? it would be helpful if you can provide the html markup of the generated auto-complete.

maybe try adding this (not tested)...

```
$( [auto-complete suggestions] ).live("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I tried that, the selection of item no longer works and it still brings me to top.

Comment: could you upload the problem somewhere where we can check?

Comment: I am working on a local network, how can i upload it ? I tried to make it work on jsFiddle but the plugin does not even work on this because of the Mime type ...

Comment: hmm...check the code snippets for each of the two plugins' `'click'` events. if it is IE that you're using, it may have something to do with the `alt` attributes.

Comment: Still have no results ... the select handler in jquery ui when empty still does that. And there is nothing on the scrollbar plugin about click event other than activating the scroll buttons (which are not in my case). Thanx for help anyway !!

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. The issue was on first time item selection it was focusing on autocomplete input element, so what i did was just focus on autocomplete input element on success of ajax and it solved my problem.

`$('#'+id of input element).focus();`